# Get and typehint the specified keys in an object

Tags: typescript

So I got an object like this, where any of the key values can be `null`

`const exampleObj = {name: 'John', surname: 'Doe', age: '77', gender: null}`

What I am trying to achieve is to pass it to a function like so

```
getRequired(object: ??, keys: ??): ?? {
   ...check if the provided keys exist in the object, and that they are not nil
}
```

The goal for this function is to return a non-null object if the provided keys exists and are not nil, if not, return undefined from the function.

Example 1 - returns undefined because one of the provided keys are null
`getRequired(exampleObj, ['name', 'surname', 'age', 'gender']) ==> undefined`

Example 2 - returns a non null object with the provided keys
`getRequired(exampleObj, ['name', 'surname', 'age']) ==> {name: string, surename: string; age: number}`

I also have to say, that all keys on the object come as
`type | null`
So What I want to do is pass it to that function, and get the object back without the `null` type.

`{name: string | null, surname: string | null, age: number | null, gender: Gender | null}`
becomes
`{name: string, surname: string, age: number, gender: Gender}`
based on which keys are passed to the function.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far

Comment: [this?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQEqoI4hgJ1QBMAeAFUVQA8pUwiBnROAIwCtVoAaRAaVQCeTarXpMAFAGtBcYIjIBKANoBdAHzi4ALnk9pQnfyEKdWXAWIkACjAiTyPIwyVgQAWxap86tYgDeALAAUIihiMBw+IjiEAgMUIj6zHL6DAr+wWFZiDBy4gCEUoI5SHDpAD7lzEr6KogAvI2IrgA2LYiV1bUNTeBEqMAwYMTpUAAW+HAA7s2oM2QCAA6oAKL4k-jiAAYsAIZEicWRhwI5TK0tWwoA3JlhAL7Bd6GEUCD4SADy7JxQAHTASZuFZgKD4GCoBjib4caB-OhgiFQsoAmAtWibcQ1FTpeq+VJ-IYQFogfpQySIXZMfSyeQKemUphmPCEUg2OwOPiCZyuDxeHy3IKPIJAA)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! [[playground link]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOB5ARgKwC4YBvAWACgZqxU5joAnASzAHMAaS6mCAV0a0U9XlBbsuVakjZwA-AzGtO3arLAATOI0Xi2MAD4wwfDBkoBfGAF5Sq43WIByAFIgAFmCeSe-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-uJyipmDZRggFAwdxQKBoa6ptAZZjCAgqMNkGDTDyoAoMmSDJgArAAzAADAhaHRAhyYAIzodEABsCEIdElBQIMaBwFuvS7u8nzfAGGDHliZ5NOitgkDA6yQjAkqciAjpNJsAC0ChUTue50YejFAsxOKNAyYAMUguBYM0XFojAFj9q+doEtAMDtNA1xiQuTDKCMOy1uiuAgCAWADGxobUK+iCoJglHYfYw6CCesZyQAktkdKDAAasSfBwP5EAMZZTlhnpsCUqYsC2LI5RVDU+Y7K56BYHg+AjOsThCGEIxOH4JXeIEkRVU4STaE46qbglNrctQDpOklGCwFqth5Keckhg2YYjVgRKyOyXVQDykTjiNPCvgAenIbVhkti1rOZMaWhoPFdIgwAYHwWjxoOYZjSUIKMJNXrJTy9WMKtC1pstT3OS9G1mRIqR6iyrSHcd9Src+Z3edGU02Ga-V+fUc2aZIKZpjl7kwAATF5WaCBA+WyhJFKgcwJ3utjYAYMKQ2rQlMAQ6lpQVNUtT1NlyC5TgBCFcVdC1RVXNlTVTVdC1-arWDMAuAAytgPw8l9bAOsKU13G9kO2BLUsy0o7Dyzsw3zSNJXEMjeUEDyJVnHrvhRgERts-gMtW8I5sWzAkSGyz7n5TNsjKxYSsJImIPZM8TpU4idAjIZUDqvxMA4wUfI+iwXo7JHEB3BT9qOs6keWRn80fB+UzGHARcAKKMB+jA7AABtkSDMFgu2RzAAAkJAlRY1etf7li6eAEB2XAPKQWwOxOK6iS2RoGpODaQA)

---

Added types to `exampleObj` to show that they resovle correctly later:

```
const exampleObj: {
   name: string,
   surname: string,
   age?: string,
   gender: string | null
} = {
   name: 'John',
   surname: 'Doe',
   age: '77',
   gender: null
}
```

Here's `getRequired`. `keys` was interesting, since it's constrained to any `string` and even when using `as const` assertion I kept getting `never` for the keys later. I found a nice expression, which converts all readonly `keys` to a union: `K[number]`. Once again, this requires passing the keys with `as const` assertion.

Removing `undefined` from the record properties is easy with `Required`, but to also remove `null`... `NonNullable` also removes `null`, but doesn't work on records. I found `RecordWithoutNullOrUndefined` type, which works on records and removes `null` and `undefined`.

```
function getRequired<T extends Record<any, unknown>, K extends string[]>(
   object: T,
   keys: K
): RecordWithoutNullOrUndefined<Pick<T, K[number]>> | undefined {
   const allKeysPresentAndNotNullish = keys
      .every(key => key in object && object[key] !== null && object[key] !== undefined);

   if (!allKeysPresentAndNotNullish) {
      return undefined
   }

   // 

   return keys.reduce((accum, key) => {
      accum[key] = object[key];

      return accum;
   }, {} as Record<any, unknown>) as RecordWithoutNullOrUndefined<Pick<T, K[number]>>;
}
```

In `tests` are your two examples, which are tested. There's also a demonstration of how the `null`s and `undefined`s are removed — check out the types for `age` and `gender` in the first test.

```
const tests: Record<string, () => boolean> = {
   // example 1
   returnUndefinedIfAnyValueIsNull() {
      const result = getRequired(exampleObj, ['name', 'surname', 'age', 'gender'] as const);
      if (result !== undefined) {
         let age = result.age;
         // ^?
         // ^^ string, undefined is excluded
         let gender = result.gender
         // ^?
         // ^^ string, null is excluded
      }

      return result === undefined;
   },

   // example 2
   returnsObjectWithProvidedKeysOnly() {
      const result = getRequired(exampleObj, ['name', 'surname', 'age'] as const);

      return JSON.stringify(result)
         === JSON.stringify({
            name: exampleObj.name,
            surname: exampleObj.surname,
            age: exampleObj.age
         })
   }
}

for (const [name, test] of Object.entries(tests)) {
   if (!test()) {
      throw new Error(`failed test ${name}`);
   }
}
```

---

**Edit1:** I suggest renaming `object` arg in `getRequired` to something else (like `obj`), since it's a reserved keyword and might mess with your IDE or types.